# How to change the clock to 12-hour format in Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, lxde, system-clock

By default, Raspbian displays a 24-hour clock:

[image]

Normally, LXDE provides an option to change the clock format by opening Panel Preferences, selecting "Digital Clock", and clicking Preferences. However, this is disabled:

[image]

How do I change the format?

Comment: Clock settings were re-enabled in Raspbian Stretch (v9). Change the time format by right-clicking the time and selecting "digital clock settings".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, the rationale for this:

> "And with regards the clock plug-in – yes, I’ve disabled the config for the time being. The clock plug-in was a nightmare from a UI point of view. For example – popping up the calendar gives you a calendar window in which you can move a highlight to show a different day – for no purpose at all. It contained a lot of kludgey hacked code for the benefit of someone who wanted the option to have their clock in bold font."
>
> — [Simon Long](https://www.raspberrypi.org/merry-christmas-got-a-new-pi/#comment-1177066)

Now for the fix. Open a terminal and run:

```
leafpad /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
```

(Substitute `leafpad` with a console editor such as `vi` or `nano` if desired.)

Locate the following line:

```
ClockFmt=%R
```

...and change it to:

```
ClockFmt=%r
```

Save the file and either reboot or restart LXDE.

Comment: As of Raspbian Stretch (v9), clock settings were re-enabled. You can right click the time and select "Digital clock settings"

Answer (score 9):

Changing the format of the time using either [Ken's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37608/84497) or [Nathan's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29656/84497) way works, but there is another difference between `%R` and `%r`. `%r` also shows the seconds ticking off. If you want them, great. If not, then you need to specify a different format, like `%I:%M %p`.

For a full list of formatting codes, see [Customizing The Clock (from archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225144423/https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/CustomizingTheClock//)

Comment: Though I like to put `%r` in the tooltip so the full tooltip is now `%A %x %r`.

Comment: That incredibly informative link is now dead :((

Comment: @XboxOne. I found the old page in archive.org and updated the above link to display that instead of the original page.

Comment: @Jim awesome, that page is actually so useful.

Answer (score 5):

#### Use `%I:%M %p` instead

The seconds from `%r` are annoying and useless.

Comment: This should probably be a comment on another answer, rather than an answer on its own.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! This duplicates another answer (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41175/19949) and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

On Pi 2, I have found right clicking on the clock, click digital clock settings, on clock format, change %R to %r

Comment: Note: his issue is that he CAN'T get to those digital clock settings.